# xamarin Android encryption GetBytes Method difference with C#

Tags: c#, android, encryption, xamarin

I have an App in Visual Studio 2013, with password Encryptation Methods, and i need to migrate it to Xamarin Android.

The problem I had is that encryptation method in Xamarin gives a different encryptation string.

The difference is in `GetBytes` Method.

Here is part of my code.

```
 public static string Encript(string ptexto, string pClave)
        {
     return Encript2(ptexto, pClave + "pass75dc@avz10", "s@lAvz", "MD5", 1, "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8", 128);
        } 


private static string Encript2(string textoQueEncriptaremos, string passBase, string saltValue, string hashAlgorithm, int passwordIterations, string initVector, int keySize)
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
            byte[] saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textoQueEncriptaremos);

            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passBase,saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations);
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);

            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged()
            {
                Mode = CipherMode.CBC
            };

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes,initVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor,CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
            return cipherText;
        }
```

The line that make the difference is

```
 byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
```

I can not change my Encryptation in my c# Applicaction, Is there a way to obtain the same result in Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation you can check, it's normal you getting different byte array, `GetByte()` always return **RANDOM** key bytes. [more](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes/)

> ```
> GetBytes(Int32) : Byte[]
> ```
>
> Returns pseudo-random key bytes.